# how to modify another user's .profile from the recovery console?

Tags: paths, recovery-mode, .profile

Pretty much everything is in the title, really! ;)
I installed a few components to compile go programs, and the last step was to add the go directory to the path.
Being a total ubuntu noob, I added the line PATH="Path/To/Folder", after the one that was already there.

After the first reboot I can no longer log into ubuntu (the screen black-out for a while and then I'm back to the login screen, and the same chime greets me.)

I've been able to boot in recovery mode, open the root's profile with vi, but I cant find my other user's profile, nor pretty much anything..

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recovery mode doesn't necessarily get all your partitions mounted(sometimes it does).  Even if it does you need to think of it as a child directory tree that isn't attached to your '/'.  Then chroot to it and everything will be where you expect.

IIRC(if i remember correctly) - recovery mode tells you where the running system's root is mounted.  With that information you can go to /where-rescue-mode-told-me-it-was-mounted/home/user/.profile

okay, so I just checked.  Been a while since I had to use recovery console.  Use the remount all as RW option before dropping to a root shell.  It drops you in /root/ as you would expect.

So to get to user .profiles:

```
cd /home
ls
cd listed_username
nano .profile
```

change your:

```
PATH="Path/To/Folder"
```

to

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder
```

You said you're using vi.  I specify nano because it's easier for new linux users.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for helping!
Is IIRC supposed to be a command?  The prompt is stating root@my-machine-name, but I cant seem to find my way to my profile, nor query it to know whether the correct partition was mounted.  Ubuntu is running in a vmWare virtual machine, so I doubt there would be more than one partition.  I didn't create anyone more.

Comment: thank you very much, that did the trick! I'm from Win world so I'm stiil hazy as to the organization of the file-system in there.  As soon as I was able to get to my .profile and edited it correctly, everything when right!

Comment: Also, I will no longer look for the IIRC command! ;)

Comment: here's the standard system organization http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html